# React Charts (recharts) Bar Chart bars greyed at upper range selection of data even with a narrow date range

Tags: recharts

even when the data range is very small, at the upper end of the scale the bars are greyed out. I understand this happens when a large range is selected but that is not the case here - it's happening even with a small range. How can I set it to have the bars fully coloured?[image] Also the XAxis label overlaps with the tick marks. Here is the code:

```
  <Grid item xs={3} md={6}>
                <BarChart
                    width={800}
                    height={300}
                    // reverseStackOrder
                    barCategoryGap={5}
                    data={barChartData}
                    margin={{
                        top: 8,
                        right: 16,
                        left: 0,
                        bottom: 8,
                    }}
                >
                    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" vertical={false} />
                    <XAxis
                        dataKey="Month-Year"
                        tick={{
                            color: "#929D8C",
                            fontSize: 10,
                            fontFamily: "Roboto, sans-serif",
                        }}
                        label={{value:"Species classes in month and year", offset:5,position:"insideBottom"}}
                        dy={4}
                    >
                    </XAxis>
                    <YAxis
                        type="number"
                        tick={{
                            color: "#F6D35B",
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontFamily: "Roboto, sans-serif",
                        }}
                        label={{ value: 'count', angle: -90, position: 'insideLeft' }}
                        dx={-8}
                    />
                    <Tooltip/>
                    <Legend verticalAlign={"top"} ></Legend>
                    {/*<Brush dataKey="Month-Year" height={30} stroke="#8884d8" />*/}
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="birds" fill="#1d6177"/>
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="insects" fill="#929D8C" />
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="plants" fill="#C85F61" />
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="reptiles" fill="#F6D35B" />
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="amphibians" fill="#33cc33" />
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="insects" fill="#ff9900" />
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="fish (ray-finned)" fill="#669999" />
                    <Bar barSize={15} dataKey="mammals" fill="#6666ff" />
                </BarChart>
            </Grid>
```